# Tiny.Cloud Not Adding Domains

Tags: tinymce

I'm trying to register a new domain in Tiny Cloud, but it doesn't seem to be saving. I'll add a domain, it'll show on my list of approved domains, but if I refresh the page it's gone and only the localhost is shown as approved.

Has anyone else experienced this? Am I missing something?

Comment: Update: Fixed the issue by very simply using a different computer to make the updates. It must've been a cache based issue. Just leaving the note in case it happens to someone else!

Comment: FYI, experiencing the same issue of not "registering" the domain in any persistent way.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me (CORS error for submitting new domain name). just use another computer or device it works fine